# How to use redis or memcached to configure tomcat6 or 7 sharing session?

Tags: java, session, tomcat, redis, memcached

I want to use redis or memcached to configure tomcat 6 or 7 sharing session, but I always configured failed.
when I use memcached, it says:java.lang.VerifyError: class de.javakaffee.web.msm.MemcachedBackupSessionManager overrides final method init.()V, when I use redis, it says:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool$Config.

Is there anyone who had configured this successfully? Please help me, show me your  configuration file, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool$Config
```

That's a classpath issue; do you have this dependency configured for apache commons?